# how to achieve label popups on imagemap

Tags: html, css

This is my first time using map tag in html.  I assume getting the tags on a image where I want is 'trial and error'

Is it possible to have a tooltip type lable when user does a mouse over on the 'clickable' part of the image? something cooler would be a comic book style tooltip :)

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<area .... title="koko" style="cursor: default;" />
```

You can take what ever cursor shape you want, Just google "css cursor".
The title attribute will give you a small floating description on the area.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go - some example code:

```
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```

Comment: I saw that too, but it doesnt have 'title' attribute which will show the label on mouseover.

Comment: The Alt Tag should help account for that.

Comment: alt attribute comes into play when an image is not loaded